# Android broadcastreceiver creates new instances

Tags: android, sms

Well, I have a class extending broadcastreceiver which is listening for messages. Now whenever it receives a message I creates a new instance of my app. So when I am closing it I have to tap back button 2 times.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage [] messages = null;
    String strMessage = "";
    String phoneNumber = "";

    if (myBundle != null) {
        Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
        messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            strMessage += " : ";
            strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
            strMessage += "\n";
            
            phoneNumber = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        }
        
        if (phoneNumber.equals("T-Mobile")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            abortBroadcast();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "creates new instance"

Comment: Please post your manifest and yes be clear about what you are seeing that you are describing as two instances.  Just describe the exact behavior and tell us whats wrong with it from your perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't really think it is creating a new instance of your app.  What is more likely happening is that an activity is being brought to the front.  I think you should look at the manifest or post it so we can see how the broadcasts are being directed.  It could be that the target of the broadcast also has the effect of starting the activity.  So check the manifest, there is nothing in the broadcast receiver that will cause this.  Having said that its really up to the Android OS what gets shown when.  But as far as two instances.  Thats just not happening.

PS. I don't know the exact reason but I would say probably don't issue Toast from a broadcast reeiver, instead communicate to an activity using startActivity().

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to issue a toast in the broadcast receiver?

Comment: Generally what you do with a broadcast receiver is to start an Activity and let the activity issue the Toast message.  Keep in mind there is both an onStart() and onCreate() method in an activity.

Comment: You should probably override both and put breakpoint to see when they are being called.

Comment: I issue toast to get see the result

Comment: Notification can be issued as well.